# Rails 4 params and "Unpermitted parameters" error

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

What I'm trying to do is just create a user (with devise):

```
  def create
    user = User.create user_params
    user.save
    render :json => user
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username)
    end
```

And it does not work because user_params return only :email and :username, without password. So I dive in and what happens - I send to server this request payload (from Chrome console):

```
{"email":"asd@asd.coma","username":"test","password":"asdasdasd","password_confirmation":"asdasdasd"}
```

What I see in console:

```
Processing by UsersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"email"=>"asd@asd.coma", "username"=>"test", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"username"=>"test", "email"=>"asd@asd.coma"}}
Unpermitted parameters: format, user
```

1. Why I have :user in `params` when I do not pass it? Why it is just copy of all rest params and why it lacking password?
2. What does `Unpermitted parameters` mean? how to fix it?
3. Why I need require(:user)? It seems like everything work fine without it.

I suppose there are simple explanation of all this things in manual or something but I can't find it (

Comment: Can you add the form / view to the question?

Comment: My other question is, if you're using devise, why aren't you just letting the `Devise::RegistrationsController` handle user creation for you?

Comment: @CDub, this form is a bit complicated and not sent as is, but after js processing it would not give more info than request payload I posted in question.

Comment: @CDub, what should I do to switch on devise's controller? Also even after switching to devise's controller, all this questions still actual for me since they helps me to understand how params processing work in Rails4.

Comment: The devise documentation has cool information about adding parameters to your submission form.  See:  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise and search for "strong parameters" ... For more about strong parameters, check this out:  http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your JSON in a root element named after the model:

```
{"user": 
  {
   "email":    "asd@asd.coma",
   "username": "test",
   "password": "asdasdasd",
   "password_confirmation": "asdasdasd"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd really need to see your view.  It looks like what is happening is you're sending additional information over in either `fields_for :user` or something similar, thus you're getting a parameter hash `:user` on create...
2. This means that you have parameters which aren't whitelisted.  In Rails 4, blacklisting parameters became the default when `strong_parameters` were added to Rails 4.  [Rails has great documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) on `strong_parameters`, and [there are blog posts](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) and [API documenation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) on `strong_parameters` as well.
3. `require(:user)` is part of strong parameters, telling your controller to expect a parameters hash called `:user` containing attributes which are permitted (thus `require(:user).permit(...)`.

Comment: here is the whole request http://screencloud.net/v/BHGx and as you can see I do not send :user or anything else.